# Programmatically displaying equations using RMarkDown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdflatex

Evening all.

I am stumped.  I have an RMarkDown document within which I need to be able to loop over a chunk a number of times, once for each item in a list.  THIS I can do readily and it all works bar one part...

I need to be able to build and display a formula which changes with each chunk iteration.  Outside the chunk (i.e. directly in the document) this is simple, with;

```
\[\alpha  =  (k/(k-1)) *  \frac{(Var(T_{P})-\sum Var)}{Var(T_{P})} \]
```

I would expect it to be something like...

```
cat("\\frac{(Var(T_{P})-\\sum Var)}{Var(T_{P})}")
```

BUT within the chunk this blows apart.

Can anyone shed light here?

Thanks

Comment: your chunk needs to have `results='asis'` to render the equation, and it should also have math delimiters

Comment: What exactly is it it that you thought would happen? http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/cat

Answer (score 0):

As `baptiste` points out it's the math-mode wrapping that makes the difference. Changing the line to `cat("$\\frac{(Var(T_{P})-\\sum Var)}{Var(T_{P})}$")` sorts it just lovely.

As a tip, using $$ centers the equation on the line which is also useful.